# lighttpd : Close its client socket by throwing error "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: c, sockets, webserver, lighttpd

I am using lighttpd webserver to host my website. It is working fine and is able to send POST and GET request. This lighttpd used cgiClient to connect to C application, is able send and receives data from C application based on a request.

But when I am trying to receive byte stream of huge size (aroung 2 - 3 GB) from C application over lighttpd server socket using Keep-Alive connection it is working fine for 12 minutes. After 12 minutes lighttpd closes its own socket by throwing error of **"Connection reset by peer"**.

So My question is that, is there any limitation based on ***size or time*** so that lighttpd closes its own socket?

Any help or advise? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Connection reset by peer" means that the client closed the connection but the server had still things to write to the client. So this is not an error caused by a limitation in lighttpd. Instead I assume that the processing of this huge post took too long and thus the client simply closed the connection to the server after some timeout before the server could send the response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are correct, my C application has more data to send to lighttpd. But lighttpd closes its socket after 12 minutes. So is there any workaround so that lighttpd will not close its socket? and my application resume to send byte data to lighttpd until it has no more data left to send.

Comment: lighttpd closes the socket because the client (your application) closed it and thus lighttpd cannot send the response any longer. "Connection reset by peer" is caused by the peer, not by the one wo throws the error. Another option might be that you have a firewall/packet filter in-between with a short connection timeout and thus the server cannot reach the client anymore.

Comment: Do you mean that my application closes the client socket? I checked the code, but i could not find anything that close the socket unexpected. My question is, is there any timeout for socket that i have to mention while creating socket using socket () system call.

Comment: You can specify a timeout for a socket but usually there is none, although some toolkits might set one. You might try a packet capture (tcpdump etc) to see if the connection is closed on the client itself or if some packet filter in between closed the connection.